# How do I configure columns in the Chatter Topics tab's Records list view?

Tags: chatter, topics

When you mark records with a topic, they display in a "records" subtab on the topic's homepage. I can't see where to configure the columns for this view. For standard objects, the columns seem to come preconfigured. For custom objects, I'm only getting the Name field.

Screenshot is for context. This is where I want to configure the columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now there is no way of customizing the fields in the Chatter Topic's Record list view.

The reason for the preconfigured list of fields for standard and custom objects is that it is based on the fields available in default list view of that object(Refer [Knowledge Article Number 000205667](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205667&language=en_US))

You can vote for this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dkp2AAC) to move it up to the product team review and will see this feature added in next few releases.